# how to detect if the UI Thread has finished working in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, performance-testing

I need to measure the performance of WPF multi-threaded application, what happens is following:
1. buttonClick is triggered in UI -> the UI thread starts processing it
2. UI thread starts another threads in background, which asyncronously do something in background and, when ready, pass the result back to the ui thread
3. Data binding occurs
4. Rendering occurs

The amount of threads is known to me, the order is not. 
How could I measure the time between the buttonClick and the end of the rendering? Is the UI thread firing an event or raise a property when it has finished? Or if not, can I make it?
Any help would be apprechiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to look on [WPF Performance Suite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx), especially on Perforator and Visual Profiler. 
On VisualProfiler you can have *"Application CPU usage details"* section one of which is:

> Render (MediaContext) Occurs during the render pass. This method
>   eventually calls the OnRender method of each element, and is useful
>   for understanding the total cost of OnRender for all elements....

or

> Rendering Thread Occurs when executing rendering instructions on the
>   rendering thread. This is useful for detecting render-bound
>   applications.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I found something possibly helpful at http://www.kynosarges.de/WpfPerformance.html:

> We cannot directly access the rendering thread but WPF does offer one
>   indirect point of access, namely through the
>   CompositionTarget.Rendering event. This event usually fires at the
>   monitor refresh rate (typically 60 times per second), whether there’s
>   any new content to render or not. It is primarily intended for custom
>   animations that need to generate display updates as quickly as the
>   monitor can show them.